# C# - Защита форм и контролов от изменения. От Winabler и её аналогов

Tags: c#, winforms, защита

Недавно я нактнулся на одну интересную программу Winaber. Она написана аж в далеком 1998 году. Программа активирует неактивные элементы в форме другой программы. Моя задача - защититься от этого. Существуют аналоги. Принцип работы у них схож. Работа происходит через вызовы API user32.dll
Как я понял, после декомпиляции этих программ, происходит следующее - перехват позиции курсора мыши, а под ним перехват имени объекта в форме (как в программе Spy++) и его последующая перерисовка. При этом свойства объектов не изменяются. Я пробовал создавать Windows Forms приложение с одним текстовым полем и задавать ему свойство Enabled = False. Вызывал обработчик событий перетаскивания мыши, обработчик состояния свойства - безуспешно. Прошу помощи в решении данного вопроса, либо любые предложения для тестирования.

Comment: Если вы задали такой вопрос, то, скорее всего, вас интересует безопасности своего софта. Лучшая защита триальной версии -- вырезание с корнем кода. Тут уж активируй - переактивируйся, а функционал не получишь

Comment: Понимаю, что можно защититься на уровне кода. Но все же интересует конкретное решение вышеописанного вопроса. Я иду в сторону функции GetMessage WinAPI, для получения входных сообщений из другой программы, если вы знаете как её правильно реализовать, напишите.

Comment: Я нашел [такую](http://sandsprite.com/CodeStuff/hackingTheUI.html#a) статью. Надеюсь вам поможет, тут как раз активируют контроллы. Причем не включая программу (ну это решается упаковкой, конечно)

Comment: Не используйте контролы WinForms - они являются обёртками WinAPI. Рисуйте свои контролы самостоятельно на Graphics - тогда никакой сторонний софт их не обнаружит.

Comment: А почему просто на уровне кода не игнорировать нажатия по активированным кнопкам? Смысл вообще тратить время на такую "защиту". Чем-то похоже на написание всей логики приложения в Form1.cs. Того же уровня "защита".

Comment: Клиентская валидация это хорошо, она повышает юзабилити, но она не отменяет валидации серверной. Серверная валидация должна быть обязательно и важнее иметь серверную, чем клиентскую. Это касается не только веб-приложений, но и десктопных, здесь мы считаем формочки клиентом, а бизнес-логику сервером. Т.е. если у вас есть своя валидация в бизнес-коде, то никакое включение отключенных кнопочек вам не страшно (про то, что злоумышленник может взломать и бизнес код я не говорю, по крайней мере это будет не так банально просто)

Comment: Я бы не стал сильно запариваться над попытками защитить свое по на стороне клиента, серебряной пули нет и что бы ты не придумал - найдутся умельцы которые это обойдут